# Form, Model, Model Form

Tags: django, django-forms

Now, I can create all the necessary db fields in my models.

I can create forms to access these models.

And if I create forms from models:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

I cant understand, why I have to redefine the Fields like these:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=3,
                widget=forms.Select(choices=TITLE_CHOICES))
    birth_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

Why do i have to define CharField here?
Didn't I do that in the models.py already?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: -1 for not reading the docs page you actually link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on what gruszczy [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546423/form-model-model-form/3546511#3546511) if you have a model named `Author` you can declare a `ModelForm` for this model thus:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm): # Note the different superclass. 
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

If you want a form that includes *all* attributes of `Author` then that is all you need to do. If however you need only a subset of attributes of `Author` (say `name` and `title`) then you can modify the model form thus:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm): # Note the different superclass. 
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title',)
```

Note that you didn't have to use `CharField` here.

If on the other hand you want *everything but* `name` and `title`, then you can define your form like this:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm): # Note the different superclass. 
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        exclude = ('name', 'title',)
```

**Update**

(After reading comment) You can treat `AuthorForm` like [any other regular form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). In your view you can instantiate this form with or without data based on the `request.method`. Something like this:

```
def add_author(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = AuthorForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthorForm(request.POST.copy())
        if form.is_valid():
             author = form.save()
             # Redirect to listing etc.

    context = dict(form = form)
    return render_to_response(template_name, context) # etc.
```

And in your template:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

There are [different ways](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) to render a form; `as_p` is but one of them.

Comment: Thanks!. And how would I insert this "Author" form  into the html code? Thanks again, evry insightful!

Comment: @MacPython: this form can be treated like any other `Form`. You can instantiate this form from the view (with or without data based on request method) and pass it along to the template. In your template you can display the form using one of the utility methods. I've updated my post to demonstrate this.

Comment: Master! Will try that! Thanks a million! So where would form.as_p go into the form html code? What does as_p stand for? Thanks again!!

Comment: @MacPython: (1) `form.as_p` will go into whichever place in the output HTML where you wish to display the form to the user (2)`as_p` will render the form as HTML using `<p></p>` tags. There are other variants to render the form as a list (`<ul></ul>`), table (`<table></table>`) etc. See the documentation for more info on those.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `forms.Form` rather than `forms.ModelForm` and declare, which model you are using (in `class Meta`). Maybe that's the problem. Could you describe, for which model of your you are having the problem?